# RavenDB cross entity query matching on non-identifier property

Tags: c#, linq, mapreduce, ravendb

I have the following entity collections in RavenDB:

```
public class EntityA
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] Tags { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] Tags { get; set; }
}
```

The only thing shared is the `Tags` collection: a tag of `EntityA` may exist in `EntityB`, so that they may intersect.

How can I retrieve every `EntityA` that has intersecting tags with `EntityB` where the `Name` property of `EntityB` is equal to a given value?

Comment: your tags suggest you have been looking in the right places - what indexes do you have in place already?

Comment: Currently I'm knee deep in MultiMapIndexes, Transforms, Includes and LiveProjections - can't get my head around this one. The workaround is to go to the database twice, but I'd much rather not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is a difficult one.  To do it right, you would need two levels of reducing - one by the tag which would expand out your results, and another by the id to collapse it back.  Raven doesn't have an easy way to do this.

You can fake it out though using a Transform.  The only problem is that you will have [skipped items](http://ravendb.net/docs/faq/skipped-results) in your result set, so make sure you know [how to deal with those](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/paging).

```
public class TestIndex : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<TestIndex.Result>
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string[] Ids { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Tag { get; set; }
    }

    public TestIndex()
    {
        AddMap<EntityA>(entities => from a in entities
                                    from tag in a.Tags.DefaultIfEmpty("_")
                                    select new
                                        {
                                            Ids = new[] { a.Id },
                                            Name = (string) null,
                                            Tag = tag
                                        });

        AddMap<EntityB>(entities => from b in entities
                                    from tag in b.Tags
                                    select new
                                        {
                                            Ids = new string[0],
                                            b.Name,
                                            Tag = tag
                                        });

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by result.Tag
                            into g
                            select new
                                {
                                    Ids = g.SelectMany(x => x.Ids),
                                    g.First(x => x.Name != null).Name,
                                    Tag = g.Key
                                };

        TransformResults = (database, results) => 
                           results.SelectMany(x => x.Ids)
                                  .Distinct()
                                  .Select(x => database.Load<EntityA>(x));
    }
}
```

See also the full unit test [here](https://gist.github.com/4532842).

There is another approach, but I haven't tested it yet.  That would be to use the [Indexed Properties Bundle](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/bundles/indexed-properties) to do the first pass, and then map those results for the second pass.  I am experimenting with this in general, and if it works, I will update this answer with the results.

Comment: Super Matt! Great work. To add, there will also be optional 'where' clauses applied when querying the index: I need some sort of 'outer join' to work so that if EntityA has 0/null tags it will still be returned in the result set. For this reason I will look into the Index Properties approach too in case the skipped results issue could interfere. Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying you want back every `EntityA`?  Or are you wanting to include the `EntityA`s that have no tags?

Comment: I want to include the `EntityA`s that have no tags.

Comment: I updated the example to show that you can do this by assigning a placeholder item using `DefaultIfEmpty`.  (The value doesn't matter as long as its non-null.)  Also updated the unit test on gist, which you should look at because it shows how sorting results can be problematic with this approach.